# allowMissing in publishHTML does not work as expected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I do not want my jenkins job to fail when it can't find the html report.

I have code like this to publishHTML report

```
publishHTML([
       reportDir:'projects..../build_report',
       reportFiles:'index.html',
       reportName:'Foo Build Report',
       keepAll:true,
       alwaysLinkToLastBuild:true,
       allowMissing:false,
])
```

I tried with `allowMissing:true` But this does not work too! My job still fails when it cannot find the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allowMissing:true` is the right param. Make sure to set it in the right job